# How do I pass arguments to a piped node script?

Tags: node.js, unix

I'd like to pass arguments to a piped node script. However the first argument to `node` takes a file. How can I bypass this and maintain the pipe?

```
echo "console.log(process.argv)" | node xxyyxx
```

> Cannot find module .../xxyyxx

Comment: `echo "..." | xargs node [file] `

Comment: @CongMa this doesn't seem to do the trick. I'd expect the params after node to be logged by the piped stdin code.

Comment: If you can modify the node script, `chmod` it to `0755`, and start it with `#!/usr/bin/env node` so you don't need `node` after the pipe in the first place.

Comment: @Ville that's not an option this is apart of a bigger script.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-` after node:

```
echo "console.log(process.argv)" | node - xxyyxx
```

Answer (score -2):

For a pipe, you could use the following construct to define the position where the pipe will output:

`echo "console.log(process.argv)" | xargs -I {} node {}`

Or, you could use command substitution if it doesn't have to be a pipe:

`node $(echo "console.log(process.argv)")`

Comment: This works! `echo "console.log(process.argv)" | xargs -I {} node -e "{}" index.js meow`

Comment: @ThomasReggi .. yep, I remembered later that I forgot your script name (`xxyyxx`) from the example above. Good thing you got it working!

Comment: @Ville Nonsense. `xxyyxx` is not script name. It is supposed to be an argument **to** a script piped from stdin.